# Java Regex vs. PHP, Dangling meta character '?'

Tags: java, php, regex

I'm tagging this with PHP even though it's a Java question.  The regex is copied from a PHP source so I'm hoping some PHPers can help with the question.

I decided to build a simple spam filter, just for fun, and I copied the spam blocklist from MediaWiki: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Spam_blacklist

Mostly this seems to work, but a few of the patterns fail with a syntax error.  I don't know if this is a typo or if PHP uses a different syntax than Java.  Can anyone help me fixing these regex so that they compile?

Here's the problems:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 17
\bfacebo(?:o[ob]|?o)k\.com\b
                 ^
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 5
\b????\.tk\b
     ^
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
??\.xsl\.pt\b
^
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 4
\b????\.shop\b
    ^
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 4
\b???\.??\b
    ^
```

Here's the code that compiles them, in case you're interested.  I don't think it makes a difference though.

```
   private static synchronized void init() throws IOException {
      
      if( blackListPatterns.get() != null ) return;
      InputStream blacklistfile = SpamBlackList.class.getResourceAsStream( "blacklist.txt" );
      BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( blacklistfile, "UTF-8" ) );
      ArrayList<String> blacklist = new ArrayList<>( 12000 );
      for( String line; (line = buf.readLine()) != null; )
         if( !line.isBlank() && line.trim().charAt(0) != '#' )
            blacklist.add( line );
      ArrayList<Pattern> tempPatterns = new ArrayList<>( blacklist.size() );
      for( String pat : blacklist )
         try {
            tempPatterns.add( Pattern.compile( pat ) );
         } catch ( java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException ex ) {
            System.err.println( ex );  // should log this, low level like FINER
         }
      blackListPatterns = new WeakReference<>( tempPatterns );
   }
   
   private static volatile WeakReference<List<Pattern>> 
           blackListPatterns = new WeakReference( null );
```

Comment: Please tell us what your regex pattern is supposed to be matching.  It seems that Java's regex engine cannot figure out to what the `?` in question should be applied.

Comment: yeah, as I mentioned, I copied the regex from elsewhere, so I don't actually know.  The first one for example seems to match spam sites where they add extra 'o' or 'b' to the "book" part of "facebook.com", but since I don't know PHP regex I'm not sure what the extra `?` might be trying to match (maybe nothing if it's a typo).  That's basically my question: what is this trying to match?

Comment: Another way of asking this question might be: *does* that `?` actually mean anything in PHP, and if so what?  Or is it a typo?

Comment: Your current regex pattern is _not_ valid in PHP, according to [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cCUtlx/1).

Comment: Ah, well, that might be the answer.  It's a typo.

Comment: I'm nowhere near an expert in regex, but I have never seen a pattern like what you showed me.  Maybe somehow this is getting past the PHP interpreter, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your downloaded copy of https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Spam_blacklist (`blacklist.txt`) is corrupt. The dangling question marks are non-ASCII characters, e.g. `\bfacebo(?:o[ob]|?o)k\.com\b` is actually `\bfacebo(?:o[ob]|ıo)k\.com\b`. Note the dotless "ı".

Download https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Spam_blacklist?action=raw and take into account that it is UTF-8.

And you may want to pass Unicode flag to the regular expressions. Also take into account that:

> What is referred to here as regular expressions are not proper regular expressions, but rather subpatterns that are inserted into a hard-coded regular expression. i.e. the subpattern Foo from above would create a regular expression like /^Foo$/usi.

(see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TitleBlacklist#Block_list).

Comment: Good detective work, I didn't think to check that.  Give me a moment while I check this out.  Edit: yup, that sorted it.  The file got corrupted somehow, or my IDE switched encoding on me.  No errors parsing the lines now.